# Is it correct to use "rescued to a place"?

Tags: phrases, verbs, sentence

I want to write a sentence in which someone is rescued and then taken to a safe place. Can I write it in following way: ?

The man was **rescued to** a safe place.

Comment: Sometimes "evacuated" is used in this case. "The man was evacuated to a safe place." This is not strictly correct usage, but it's common and widely understood.

Comment: Doesn't this belong on ELL.SE, not English.SE?  Hopefully a mod can migrate it, since it's already answered.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

No. This would imply that "rescue" is a form of transport - akin to saying "flown to a safe place" or "driven to a safe place".

While driving and flying may form part of the rescue, they are not part of the definition of the word rescue, which involves changing someone's situation  from "being in danger" to "being safe".  The actual act of rescue might only involve moving them a very short distance - eg from being in the sea to being on a boat.

You can say that someone was "rescued from" something - eg *"rescued from a flood"*.  But we don't say that they were "rescued **to**" somewhere, even if the rescue involved moving them to that place.

You could say "The man was rescued and taken to a nearby hospital" for example.  Saying that he was "taken to a safe place" would be assumed from the very fact that he'd been rescued, so is redundant.

Comment: Rescue CAN be connected to space, but is not implicitly connected to it. Rescue is a change of state. So, the distance can be not only small, but null. We can rescue from a flood by simply stopping the water.

Comment: http://www.wmcactionnews5.com/story/32284554/dog-abandoned-at-former-shelter-rescued-to-foster-home ; http://www.watchthemed.net/reports/view/511 ;